# laravel get data ajax tos how val is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
/* When click show user */

$(document).on("click", '#edit', function() {
  var userURL = $(this).data('url');
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $.get(userURL, function(data) {
    $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      $('#title').val(value.title)
      alert(value.title);
    });

    $('#edit_forms').attr('actions', data.editRoute);
  })
});
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Category name">
```

I tested value   `alert(value.title);` it passes but                `$('#title').val(value.title)` to show input shows `undefined`.  How to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Remove input from body and add it to your JS and instead of input create a div with desired id. Add id to append.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
 $('#your title div').append('<input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Category name" value="' + value.title + '">');
```

Comment: FYI `#title` is an `<input>` element